# Adding multiple chapter names in mkv files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

when I'm multiplexing video, audio and subtitle files into one mkv file I'm using ffmetadata files like this to add chapters:

```
;FFMETADATA1
title=Hello world
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/25
START=0
END=2821
title=Prologue
type=prologue
```

Now I saw that mkv supports [multiple chapter names for different languages](http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/chapters/index.html) and I'm wondering if this is possible with ffmpeg?